# Printing issue with HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am facing issue while print image in chrome, I tried to print in Firefox it works.

Below is my sample code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>   
        <input 
            type="button" 
            value="Print this page" 
            onclick="printpage()"  
            style="height: 65px; width: 140px; top: 890px; left: 510px; position: absolute;">          
        <img 
            src="BuilderLogo.png" 
            id="ctl02_tabEBrochures_55_" 
            style="height: 65px; width: 140px; top: 1050px; left: 810px; position: absolute;">    
        <input 
            type="button" 
            value="Print this page" 
            onclick="printpage()"  
            style="height: 65px; width: 140px; top: 1050px; left: 510px; position: absolute;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Function "PrintPage()" just has `Window.print()`.

When I print the page, images do not print. However, they show when I open it in the browser.

As I show in the screenshots below, I have added two print buttons. In print, only the first print button is showing.

I notice that when I set top of any image control more than 900px, than I am facing this issue.

Original Page:
[image: image on screen with two print buttons showing]

Print Ouptput:

[image: image on print with only one button showing]

What could be the problem?

Comment: is it printed in second page maybe due to position pixels?

Comment: Apostolos: No, it's print in single page, but after 900px no one images are shown in print.

Comment: Look at your stylesheet. Here's what I did http://jsfiddle.net/VWeYV/3/

Comment: @chiragKhatsuriya if you test with kush's fiddle and add the absolute pixels for the image, the image is printed in second page

Comment: Apostolos & Kush: Thx for reply. I found that when I print the page using "Print Using System Dialog", than these images are not print, otherwise it's export to "One Note" and "PDF" properly.

Comment: Apostolos & Kush: any Idea? why this thing happen?

Answer (score 1):

While you need to define a separate stylesheet for print rather than using the same one as for screen, I suspect that your issue is something as simple as Chrome disabling the printing of images. See the following screenshot for how to enable:

[image: Chrome print options]

Comment: Chris P: I have check this option. You can see above print image, the button is printed with image and without image.